# Using update cursor to populate a field based on a Date field in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I'm trying to populate a field (Season, "TEXT") in my attribute table with a season code based on a sampling date (FIXDATE, "DATE"). For example sample collected between 01/01/2016 and 01/03/2016 would get season code "SPRING". I'm new to arcpy and search cursors. Here is my code so far.

```
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime

caribou = "C:/Python/Test_data.gdb/test_data"
fields = ['FIXDATE', 'Season']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(caribou, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0] >= datetime.strptime("01/01/2016", "%d/%m/%y") and row[0] <= datetime.strptime("01/03/2016", "%d/%m/%y")):
            row[1] = "SPRING"
        elif (row[0] >= datetime.strptime("02/03/2016", "%d/%m/%y")and row[0] <= datetime.strptime("01/06/2016", "%d/%m/%y")):
            row[1] = "SUMMER"
        elif (row[0] >= datetime.strptime("02/06/2016", "%d/%m/%y") and row[0] <= datetime.strptime("01/10/2016", "%d/%m/%y")):
            row[1] = "FALL"
        elif (row[0] >= datetime.strptime("02/10/2016", "%d/%m/%y")):
            row[1] = "WINTER"

    # Update the cursor with the updated list
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: What's happening so far with your result? Not sure if this was a copy/paste error, but you need to indent your cursor loop (`for row in cursor...` inside the `with` statement.

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Are there errors or just a result you're not expecting/wanting?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have been getting this error message:
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `row[0]` to the same format as your `datetime.strptime("02/06/2016", "%d/%m/%y")`, and also your `%y` needs to be `%Y` for the 4 digit year.  I have added an extra line `myDate = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(row[0], "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d/%m/%Y")` to convert the `row[0]` and then use that in each `if`/`elif` for comparison.

```
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime

caribou = "C:/Python/Test_data.gdb/test_data"
fields = ['FIXDATE', 'Season']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(caribou, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        myDate = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(row[0], "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d/%m/%Y")
        if (myDate >= datetime.strptime("01/01/2016", "%d/%m/%Y") and myDate <= datetime.strptime("01/03/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")):
            row[1] = "SPRING"
        elif (myDate >= datetime.strptime("02/03/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")and myDate <= datetime.strptime("01/06/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")):
            row[1] = "SUMMER"
        elif (myDate >= datetime.strptime("02/06/2016", "%d/%m/%Y") and myDate <= datetime.strptime("01/10/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")):
            row[1] = "FALL"
        elif (myDate >= datetime.strptime("02/10/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")):
            row[1] = "WINTER"

    # Update the cursor with the updated list
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```